# How to resolve this "positional arguments in functional tests has been deprecated" warning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 5 introduced some  deprecation messages in my tests

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using positional arguments in functional tests has been deprecated,
in favor of keyword arguments, and will be removed in Rails 5.1.

Deprecated style:
get :show, { id: 1 }, nil, { notice: "This is a flash message" }

New keyword style:
get :show, params: { id: 1 }, flash: { notice: "This is a flash message" },
  session: nil # Can safely be omitted.
```

For this most part, these have been easy to resolve. The instructions are pretty clear in the message.

But I'm still getting these warnings for controller specs that test strong params.

How should the following be rewritten to prepare for Rails 5.1?

```
let(:user) { create :user }
it { is_expected.to permit( :name, :email ).for(:update, params: { id: user.to_param, user: valid_attributes } ).on(:user) }
```

Comment: i guess you are using some shoulda? that might need an updated version.

Comment: thanks @phoet, yes I am using should matchers. But my question may be more general than this (not sure as I'm a little confused by the controller changes Rails 5 has introduced, and what is now the "Rails Way"). It appears that one should not test controller internals, and that controller specs are not the way forward https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950. In broad terms, how and where would you test that a controller permits the correct params in Rails 5?

Comment: maybe you should rephrase your question then? i think getting rid of controller tests in favor of integration tests is stupid, but i'm not DHH, so what do i know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for(:update, params: { params: { id: user.to_param, user: valid_attributes } })
```

It's ugly, but that worked for me.

**Update**: found my workaround and fix number here
https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/867